# My tor won't start, is there external interface on my device?

Tags: configuration, startup, polipo

> Every time i start it up it states vertualy the same text everytime...
>   Everything seems to run fine till it starts to connect to"Polipo" saying connection refused each time 
>   Help?
>
> ```
>  Orbot is starting…
>  Waiting for control port...
>  Connecting to control port: 49469
>  SUCCESS connected to Tor control port.
>  SUCCESS - authenticated to control port.
>  Starting Tor client… complete.
>  adding control port event handler
>  SUCCESS added control port event handler
>  Tor started; process id=4717
>  Starting polipo process
>  Set background service to FOREGROUND
>  Couldn't find Polipo process... retrying...
> ```

```
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
WARN: Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:443 ("Connection refused") 
Couldn't find Polipo process... retrying...

Couldn't find Polipo process... retrying...

Polipo is running on port:8118
Polipo process id=-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that your Tor instance seems to be not fully bootstrapped yet, i.e. not able to serve requests. Give it some time - and check for 100% bootstrap message, and *after 100% bootstrap* take a look at "bandwidth self-test" message in the log. After 100% you will be able to use Tor + whatever uses it, but after a bandwidth self-test it's usually faster. The messages are look like this:

```
Nov 18 05:25:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

and

```
Nov 18 05:25:29.000 [notice] Performing bandwidth self-test...done.
```